# Deciding finite prefix language of a real number

Tags: turing-machines

why is the language of finite prefixes of the number pi decidable by a TM whereas it is false to say there is a TM for **any** real number that which decides the finite prefixes of that given number?

Comment: yeah maybe...but I just don't find the answer. The only thing I can think of is, there are uncomputable numbers...

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the language of finite prefixes of the number pi decidable by a TM

There is an effective computational procedure to print out finite prefixes of the digits of pi. The Maclaurin series for sin(x) is x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - ... Furthermore, we know that sin(pi/2) = 1, so we can set 1 = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - ..., start somewhere close (like x = 1.5) and find the largest value of x that increased over its predecessor. Then, multiply this by 2 and keep the first n digits to get a prefix of length n. For instance:

```
f(1.50) < f(1.51) < f(1.52) < f(1.53) < f(1.54) < f(1.55) < f(1.56) < f(1.57)
f(1.59) < f(1.58) < f(1.57)
```

This tells us that x = 1.57 is the closest value to pi/2 and is either a little bigger or a little smaller than we really need. We can tell by checking the Maclaurin series for cos(x): we see that cos(1.57) converges to a positive number, so we know we are on the largest number with n digits that is less than pi/2. Keep the computation at least one level lower than you need to return digits of pi and everything will turn out fine.

> whereas it is false to say there is a TM for any real number that which decides the finite prefixes of that given number

Here is a real number for you: the real number between 0 and 1 whose decimal representation as the nth digit set to 1 if and only if the nth Turing machine (determined by lexicographical ordering of the UTM encoding of all TMs) accepts the empty language. This is a well-defined real number - each of its decimal digits is either 0 or 1 - and yet if we had a TM that could find any finite prefix of this real number, we could answer the question "does this TM accept the empty language?" for any TM by:

- encoding the TM in the UTM encoding
- enumerating all strings in lexicographical order and counting how many valid UTM encodings of TMs we find
- halting the computation when we count the TM we want the answer for
- asking for a prefix whose length is equal to the count we just got
- checking the last digit of the prefix to see whether our TM accepts the empty language or not

This is a contradiction since it is undecidable whether a TM accepts the empty language or not. Therefore, our assumption that we could compute finite prefixes of this real number was incorrect.

For any undecidable problem involving TMs (Rice's theorem and diagonalization arguments guarantee that most languages of UTM encodings of TMs are) you get a unique real number which cannot be computed. Indeed, the computable real numbers are countable, just like Turing machines, but unlike languages and real numbers, which are uncountable.